# Suggestions for comparing two booleans in an if-statement in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean, boolean-expression

I am having an issue with some code that I have written.

I am writing in c++, and I am trying to set up 3 strings, all of which are "off". I am also trying to set up 2 booleans to be `false` at the beginning of the program. All of this beginning code works.

I want to set up an if statement, so that if the booleans are both `true` at the same time, then all of the strings will change to "on", and then the program will print an output saying they are on.

I have looked online, but couldn't find an answer, so if you have any ideas, I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Here's the code for reference:

```
//imports the required utilities for the program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//sets up the main method 
    int main()
    {
//declares and assigns all variables needed for program
        string light1 = "off";
        string light2 = "off";
        string electricity = "off";
        bool power(false);
        bool pressure(true);
//prints the outcome to indicate that the electricity is off to begin with
        std::cout << ("The Electricity is " + electricity +", Light #1 is "+ 
light1 +" and Light #2 is "+ light2 +".");
//introduces if statement to turn on electricity in lights
        if ((power) && (pressure))
        {
            string light1 = "on";
            string light2 = "on";
            string electricity = "on"; 
        }
//prints the new outcome to indicate if the electricity is on
        cout << "\n";
        std::cout << ("The Electricity is " + electricity +", Light #1 is "+ 
light1 +" and Light #2 is "+ light2 +"."); 
     }
```

Comment: Question is not clear. I think your comparison is fine

Comment: "I am also trying to set up 2 booleans to be false at the beginning of the program." - `pressure` is declared `true` at the beginning of your program.

Comment: instead of `cout << (a + b + c)`, do `cout << a << b << c`. It worked out in this case but may have problems in future

Comment: Don't put so many comments to explain what you did, especially just to tell the reader you initialized variables. If a piece of code does something that deserves a name/description, put it in a function, name and call *that*. That way the actions your code preforms are written right there, and not in a comment that compilers (and people) ignore.

Comment: And maybe just use `if (power && pressure)` (no extra brackets needed)

Comment: The `&&` statement compares two statements and evaluates if both are true. In this case, one of them is false, so the `if` statement would not work. As Shubham said, your comparison seems fine.

Comment: @JedaiCoder `&&` is an operator and it does not compare the two operands. It evaluates the first operand unconditionally, but short-circuits on the second

Comment: True, but for the statement to execute, the if statement should evaluate `true`, which is not happening.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring three new string variables that only exist in the scope of that if statement. Remove the datatypes to assign values to the strings outside of the if statement, like so

```
if ((power) && (pressure))
{
    light1 = "on";
    light2 = "on";
    electricity = "on";
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, that worked and now the program works great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Fix below.  Don't redeclare the variables in the if statement, C++ has a concept of scope, for more on that look here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope.  Also its considered really bad to add a `using namespace std;` at the top of an implementation file (it's fine for small examples like yours, but be careful for the future)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string light1 = "off";
    string light2 = "off";
    string electricity = "off";
    bool power(false);
    bool pressure(true);

    cout << ("The Electricity is " + electricity +", Light #1 is "
            + light1 +" and Light #2 is "+ light2 +".") << endl;

    power = pressure = true;
    if ((power) && (pressure))
    {
        light1 = "on";
        light2 = "on";
        electricity = "on";
    }

    cout << ("The Electricity is " + electricity +", Light #1 is "
            + light1 +" and Light #2 is "+ light2 +".") << endl;
}
```